# Java servlets: how to display a page?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using a Java Servlet to do some work (validate user login, update session values, etc.) and I want to redirect to an existing JSP page when I'm done. How do I do that?

Comment: Put your mouse above the `servlets` tag below the question and wait until a box pops up. In the box, click the *info* link. It contains a pretty useful Hello World example.

Answer (score 2):

```
response.sendRedirect("page.jsp");
```

Comment: True, but it doesn't pass the request and response to another jsp. Except, it does an HTTP-Redirect.

Comment: what he ask he got concrete answer.

Answer (score 2):

also to `sendRedirect` take a look at

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/foo/foo.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

redirect is useful then you changed some information (e.g. made a post in the forum) so redirecting will prevent double posting.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` , you can also set the http response header and status code to `SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY (301)` or `SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY (302)`

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);  
response.setHeader("Location", "http://www.xxx.yyy/");
```

Comment: The OP wants to send his responses to his JSP and not do a redirect to another site. This won't work.

Comment: The OP only says he wants to "redirct" to an existing JSP page , he did not mention he wants to pass the HttpServletResponse and HttpServletRequest to another jsp. I only supplement  another way to do "redirect" for the OP 's reference